# Finding if item is in Apple

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have a database called appleList. Within it I have apple objects which within them has a list of items. I'm attempting to create a method where it returns true if item j is within the list of customer r and false if its not. This is what I have come up with so far...

```
public boolean (String m)
{
        if(n[i] = p)
            found = true;
    return found;
}
```

Comment: What is `customerList` in your code?

Comment: its an ArrayList

Comment: But there is no declaration in the above code for the same. Also `n[i]` does that even compile?

Answer (score 1):

Use equals() to compare Strings. Also, if n is an array you need to pass it in like below

```
public boolean hasProduct(String[] n, String p)
{
boolean found = false;
for(int i=0; i < n.size(); i++)
    if(n[i].equals(p))
        found = true;
return found;
}
```

Comment: you have change the arguments from the original question

Answer (score 1):

There's an existing method in List that you can use

```
customerList.contains(object)
```

This method return `true` if the list contains the object

If you are using a custom object you can override the method `equals`, so the method above will use it to compare all objects in your list

```
public class MyCustomClass{
    private Integer id;

    //Other variables, getters and setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o2){
        if(o2 instanceof MyCustomClass){
           MyCustomClass o2custom = (MyCustomClass) o2;
           if(o2custom.getId()!=null && this.id != null){
               return o2custom.getId() == this.id;
           }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hugs

Comment: You can get weird behavior if you don't override Object.equals(), so I would suggest that you always do this if you want to use your custom objects in collections. Override Object.hashcode() while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

String n is not an array n[0] is wrong try this :

```
    public boolean hasProduct(String p)
{
    boolean found = false;
    for(int i=0; i < customerList.size(); i++)
        if(customerList.get(i) == p)
            found = true;
    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate an ArrayList you need to use .get(). Also, I added a break in your loop once the item is found.

```
public boolean hasProduct(String n, String p)
{
    boolean found = false;
    for(int i=0; i < this.customerList.size(); i++)
       if(this.customerList.get(i) == p)
          found = true;
           break;
    return found;
}
```

Comment: so I don't have to implement String n anywhere at all?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for a String in an ArrayList, you can simply do something like this:

```
public boolean hasProduct(ArrayList customerList, String p)
{
    return customerList.contains(p);
}
```

As @DigaoParceiro mentions, if you're looking for a custom object within your collection, be sure to override equals() and hashCode(). String already provides this for you.